# Are there any good and free libraries to develop web applications in C?

Tags: c

I've searched the web a bit, but all I found were abandoned projects and only CGI support.

EDIT 1: C isn't just used for writing drivers or embedded systems. We have mailreaders, newsreaders, editors, etc. all written in C. I've written two BBS in the last century before the web became popular. The libraries are getting better and you don't have to reinvent the wheel over and over again. Nice data structures and string handling is easily possible in C. But yet, there's not much going on in web development.

I'd like to come back to my roots and try to write web applications in C.

As for *bad languages*: People use C++, Perl, and PHP for web applications. It doesn't stop them that the common perception of these languages isn't very good.

EDIT 2: I've written BBS software in C and nobody thought this was a crazy idea, although others have done it in GfA BASIC back then. I don't understand why today it should be considered a bad idea. Have a look at the software you are using or the most common programming languages in open-source software.

Comment: Thsi begs the question: why would you want to?  Manual memory management, etc, ugh.  Is there some requirement you have that necessitates C for this?

Comment: web apps in c ?? I would say that is a definite no-no

Comment: @cletus: An object that is always referenced will not be freed by the GC. You can make mistakes in memory management in all languages and system. It's less likely if you are aware of the problems. No requirements, just fun to program.

Comment: @Vijay Dev: People use PHP, too. And most PHP programs have a terrible security record. In discussions it gets defended because the developer is to blame and not his tools. My e-mail reads is written in C. And so is my editor, my news reader, etc.

Comment: language/platform != security

Comment: As a C fan who likes all the things that most people hate about C, I still wouldn't use it for web development. Plus, I don't think it's a "common perception" that Perl is a bad language. Many people write a lot of very good Perl. Honestly, you can write much harder to grok C with the preprocessor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

clearsilver should do the  job fine
http://www.clearsilver.net/docs/

and if you need some GC stuff you always can use the boehm weisser gc.

Regards
Friedrich

Comment: On the first look clearsilver only offers CGI. But there are flexible hooks and a (broken) example how to use it with FastCGI. Looks usable to me.

Answer (score 6):

If you're adventurous and open to a new web server, take a look at [G-WAN](http://gwan.com/en_faqs.html). It serves dynamic content with ANSI-C scripts. It's small, [fast](http://gwan.com/index.html), and free (though not open source). Browse the [running samples with source](http://gwan.com/en_developers.html) to get a feel for G-WAN development.

If you spend time on the G-WAN site, you'll notice that its developer, Pierre Gauthier, has strong opinions about the state of software development today. Agree or disagree, his perspective is interesting given the increasing size and complexity of the tools we use everyday.

Comment: Thank you. Sounds very promising.

Comment: Oh, "strong opinions". He wants to implement everything himself because others are morons. And I couldn't find any source, only a 32 bit binary for Linux (Ubuntu). Even the forum threads about accessing NoSQL databases just end in the announcement of him integrating some key-value store he is currently writing all by himself.

Comment: His 'wait-free' Key-Value store is several orders of magnitude faster (and more scalable) than any other noSQL DB (he provides tests), so that may not have been so stupid. The same goes with G-WAN in the first place (faster, more scalable). Oh, and there's a 64-bit release too. On the top of that, you can use any library from G-WAN Java, C, C++, Objective-C and D scripts so there is no reason to complain about G-WAN providing (faster) alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

As others have noted C is not the best language for developing a web application.  However, if the application's core is already written in C, AND you are ok with only a single user accessing the application at the time, AND you can trust that user (for instance, because the application will only be made available behind a firewall), then the [swill library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swill/) is an interesting choice.  It is an embedded web server, which with a handful of lines can provide a web interface to any C application.  I've used it twice, for the [CScout refactoring browser](http://www.spinellis.gr/cscout) and for providing a user interface to legacy production line optimization code, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

I've used [GNU libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/) and it is excellent: clear API; lightweight; open source and still actively developed; and it embedded nicely into our existing C application. Importantly, it is licensed under the LGPL, but [Hughes libhttpd](http://www.hughes.com.au/products/libhttpd/) has a dual license, which may be an issue for commercial projects. (Credit to Jakob Eriksson's answer for getting there first.)

Edit: Also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298113/how-can-i-implement-a-restful-webservice-using-c/604745#604745).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Swill, I would look at [GNU libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/) and [Hughes libhttpd](http://www.hughes.com.au/products/libhttpd/).
Both are intended to embed web servers in programs. I was nearly deciding on [Hughes](http://www.hughes.com.au/products/libhttpd/) for a web frontend of sorts for [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html) but may go the Python route instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [libevent](http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/). It has a [HTTP server](http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/doxygen-1.4.9/evhttp_8h.html).

Comment: I read on the HTTP server in libevent, but there doesn't seem an easy (or well documented) to access the fields of a POST request.

Comment: I also had a hard time with `libevent`'s "documentation" (or lack thereof). I ended up writing my own, which was super fun and the code is heavily commented for future documentation. [You can have a look](https://github.com/boazsegev/c-server-tools).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, maybe someone would find it usefull: [klone](http://www.koanlogic.com/klone/).
It is a framework for building standalone web serververs and html templating with
embedded C.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the naysayers that say that C is not acceptable or advisable.  The assumption that they make is that they are writing your application.  This can be a good learning experience for you.

C has some very specific advantages over other modules.  You can easily write a  framework for it that does a lot of the heavy lifting for your application, without too much effort.

The danger is the safety and sanity of your code.   The advice that I have is to try Django or Rails and see how they 'do it', then take the best of their ideas back to C.

Your development time may be "slower", but on the other hand you will have intimate knowledge of your stack and framework.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of a library, but if you could visit this site
[vijaymukhi.com](http://www.vijaymukhi.com/)  you could find some learning projects developed using C.

You can specifically check the "Air Ticket Reservation" and "Ecommerce Modules".

NOTE:  This is only a learning projects with c and cgi.

Please check the "Projects(with source)" section on the treemenu.

P.S:  I don't recommend this for production/live sites.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very specific requirement to use C, you should probably rethink your language choice. Even with a framework (which as you've noticed, are hard to come by these days), a webapp in C is likely to be very error-prone, especially to buffer overlows related to untrusted user input.

If you have some SDK or legacy code in C that you need to access, and no alternative but to use it, you can still get at this in various ways from another language.

For example in Java there is JNI. And you can always wrap the SDK in a CLI program that does what you need, and run it from your webapp (which can then be written in any language). The same caveats about buffer overflows etc will apply, but at least you can program defensively in the CLI program (i.e. don't trust your arguments and sanitize them before using).

Another alternative may be to use IPC to a process which provides access to the 'C' SDK or legacy code functions. Same arguments about defensive programming apply.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to think of any situation where C is the best language to develop a web app. Just as you wouldn't want to write a GUI app in FORTRAN or a device driver in COBOL.

Why not try PHP? The syntax is fairly similar to C.

Comment: To some extend the question always could have  been. Why C, to ask this now just  neglects the fact that every current OS in wider use was written in C, and every database was written in C. So C still has it's place....

Comment: Yes, C has it's place. But not for web apps.

Comment: Well it's your right to decide so but: have you tried C for web apps?
Every language was used for web development and so I bet that quite a few older pages have use C-CGI programs, and it probably has worked well for them

Answer (score 0):

Well, years ago I wrote a "CSP" compiler, a very basic equivalent to JSP, but in C. It generated CGI C code. I guess you could use THAT as a base or for simple experimentation. I never did anything with it so you can have it if you want (and if I can find it)... just drop me a line.

Answer (score 0):

See [C HyperText Library](http://hackersden.ml/chl).

Its a library for writing web applications in C. It provides you with all the functionallity you need to create great web apps, as well as support for inline functions inside the HTML files.

Comment: I think CGI is, or should be, obsolete. The resource requirements and limits of CGI execution have long been surpassed by memory persistent web applications that use different communication techniques (i.e., running an internal web server, such as Node.js and Rails and using a Proxy connection)... your heart is in the right place, but I think the library doesn't fit the bill.

Answer (score -1):

Why not convert your legacy C code into a php / apache plugin? Then you've got the best of both worlds, modern web based language / server but utilising all the existing code in your legacy application.

Comment: Then my advice is definately not to bother using C/C++ to develop a web app. There are much better languages and frameworks you can use.
PHP is a good suggestion as it's syntax is similar to C/C++. However C# / ASP.NET might be better for you.

Comment: I already used Perl, Java, PHP, Ruby, Python, etc. for web development.